# how can i use this fileupload in a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

hi i found this fileupload today and it kinda fits like a glove for a form im doing, my only problem is how do i upload this file to server? i know it say to put it in a form but im still confused.

the input script i use it like this, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/custom-file
my setup looks like this.

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="upload" value="Add A Showreel" />
```

ACTION

```
foreach (string item in Request.Files)
{
    count++;
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item];
    if (file != null)
    {


    }
}
```

my thing is i dont know if i should place the file in some kind of hidden field or what for the request.files to pick it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // If the user selected a file it will be stored 
            // in the special App_Data folder
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var filename = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

then a view:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-custom-file-input.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myForm" })) { %>
    <input type="button" class="upload" value="Add a file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<% } %>
```

and finally a javascript file to apply the plugin to the button and scriptify the markup:

```
$(function() {
    $('.upload').file().choose(function (e, input) {
        // The controller action expects the file input to be named "file"
        input.attr('name', 'file');

        // let's hide the ugliness
        input.hide();

        // append the file input to the original form 
        // that we will be posting to the server
        $(input).appendTo('#myForm');
    });
});
```

Must read blog before ever using `Request.Files` in an ASP.NET MVC controller action: [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example for image uploads.  I'm sure you can modify it for videos (I'm assuming since your button says "Showreel"):

The html is the same as yours, but here's the C# code:

```
foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
  if (file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    Byte[] fileByte = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(fileByte, 0, file.ContentLength);

    // Add code here to save fileByte to your database.
  }
}
```

Since I am using images, my database has an image entry, which I set equal to fileByte.  In order to get the file, I use the following code:

```
public FileContentResult Image(int id)
{
  Infographic infographic = GetInfographic(id);

  return new FileContentResult(infographic.image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

In this case, GetInfographic(int id) returns a unique entry from the database with the specified id.  I then have the function return a FileContentResult with the image from the entry in the database and I tell it it's "image/jpeg".  There is a list of MIME content types that you can use [herehere](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm).  I used "image/jpeg" since I'm sending an image, but in your case I'd use "video/mpeg" or something similar.

Comment: im not having problems to upload files, just to use this jquery "fake" input. but thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. -1 for not reading what is being asked here. And another -1 for using `Request.Files` in a controller action instead of using strongly typed action arguments of type `HttpPostedFileBase`.